# Excel: How to replace one of two matching columns with third

Tags: excel, replace

Í have two spreadsheets.

**Column A**  has values.

**Column B** has the same values but in different order.

**Columns C,D,F** are also important and related to **Column A**.

I need to find the matching values from **Column A** and **Column B**.

And replace the values in **Column B** with the **Columns C,D,F**.

Thank you preliminary!

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `vlookup()`.  This function searches through a given column for the first value that matches a variable that you have set.  It then steps n columns to the right and returns the value.

This function will not replace the values in column B with the desired values in C, D, & F.  Rather you must create a new column and select the desired value from each column according to rules that you set.

It is unclear to me whether you wish to combine columns C, D, & F (in which case you should use the `concatanate()` function), or only display the values in one column based on some priority system.  Concatenating the values is relatively simple, as mentioned above.  Prioritizing the columns requires setting up some `if / else` statements to govern the condition under which each column C, D, or F will be returned.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on the image that you have appended in the comment below, I would suggest you place the following function in cell D2:

```
=vlookup(C2,A$2:B$8,2,0)
```

Then drag this equation down the length of column D, from row 2 to row 8.  The references will automatically be adjusted for each row.

As a side note, I usually place the `Number` and `Price` columns into a tab of their own.  If you go to the bottom left of the page you'll see that you can create a new tab (and title it whatever you like).  It is important keep that information visually separate because you are using it as a lookup table.  While lookup tables are important, they do not need to be visible on the main spreadsheet at all times.  Plus, they almost always have a different number of rows than the data set being analyzed (in this case I'm guessing you would be analyzing `Number-2` and `Price-2`).  So it becomes awkward to display the lookup table and main data set side by side.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LVfz6.png
Here is my table. I need to match the numbers in columns A and C and extract the linked prices from B to D. Columns A and B are fixed, they are my reference numbers and prices.

Thank you!